# Scrapy not process all page when crawling

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scraper

I create crawler with scrapy. And create some script for crawling many pages.

Unfortunately, not all script crawling all page. Some page return all page, and other just 23 or maybe 180 (Different result each URL).

```
import scrapy

class BotCrawl(scrapy.Spider)
    name = "crawl-bl2"
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.bukalapak.com/c/perawatan-kecantikan/perawatan-wajah?page=1&search%5Bsort_by%5D=last_relist_at%3Adesc&utf8=%E2%9C%93',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.css("ul[class='products row-grid']"):
            for product in product.css('li'):
                yield {
                 'judul': product.css('a[class="product__name line-clamp--2 js-tracker-product-link"]::text').extract(),

                 'penjual': product.css('h5[class=user__name] a::attr(href)').extract(),

                 'link': product.css('a[class="product__name line-clamp--2 js-tracker-product-link"]::attr(href)').extract(),

                 'kota': product.css('div[class=user-city] a::text').extract(),

                 'harga': product.css('div[class=product-price]::attr(data-reduced-price)').extract()

            }

        # next page    

        next_page_url = response.css("div.pagination > a[class=next_page]::attr(href)").extract_first()
        if next_page_url is not None:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page_url))
```

Its is blocking from http request or maybe something error on my code?

**Updated code after after edited by Granitosaurus**

Still error

[return blank array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIhhs.png)

```
import scrapy


class BotCrawl(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "crawl-bl2"
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.bukalapak.com/c/perawatan-kecantikan/perawatan-wajah?page=1&search%5Bsort_by%5D=last_relist_at%3Adesc&utf8=%E2%9C%93',
    ]


def parse(self, response):
    products = response.css('article.product-display')
    for product in products:
        yield {
        'judul': product.css('a[class="product__name line-clamp--2 js-tracker-product-link"]::text').extract(),
        'penjual': product.css('h5[class=user__name] a::attr(href)').extract(),
        'link': product.css('a[class="product__name line-clamp--2 js-tracker-product-link"]::attr(href)').extract(),
        'kota': product.css('div[class=user-city] a::text').extract(),
        'harga': product.css('div[class=product-price]::attr(data-reduced-price)').extract()
        }


    # next page    

    next_page_url = response.css("div.pagination > a[class=next_page]::attr(href)").extract_first()
    last_url = "/c/perawatan-kecantikan/perawatan-wajah?page=100&search%5Bsort_by%5D=last_relist_at%3Adesc&utf8=%E2%9C%93"
    if next_page_url is not last_url:
      yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page_url),dont_filter=True)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your products xpath is a bit unreliable. Try selectic product articles directly, the site makes it very easy for you to do with css selectors:

```
products = response.css('article.product-display')
for product in products:
    yield {
        'judul': product.css('a[class="product__name line-clamp--2 js-tracker-product-link"]::text').extract(),
        'penjual': product.css('h5[class=user__name] a::attr(href)').extract(),
        'link': product.css('a[class="product__name line-clamp--2 js-tracker-product-link"]::attr(href)').extract(),
        'kota': product.css('div[class=user-city] a::text').extract(),
        'harga': product.css('div[class=product-price]::attr(data-reduced-price)').extract()
    }
```

You can debug response by inserting `inspect_response`:

```
def parse(self, response):
    products = response.css('article.product-display')
    if not products:
        from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
        inspect_response(response, self)
        # will open up python shell here where you can check `response` object
        # try `view(response)` to open it up in your browser and such.
```

Comment: Its still not crawl all page. Thats only return till pages 28. https://snag.gy/CpyAXP.jpg

Comment: @RadenJohannesHeryoPriambodo works fine for me. What exactly happens on page 28? No products are found? You can add debug break point to see what's going on, see my edit.

Comment: I mean the crawler stopped until page 28. page 1-27 running well. @Granitosaurus

Comment: after insert debug the return till page 30. but still error here is the error. check this out https://ctrlv.cz/wuW4

Comment: DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://www.bukalapak.com/c/perawatan-kecantikan/perawatan-wajah?page=31&search%5Bsort_by%5D=last_relist_at%3Adesc&utf8=%E2%9C%93> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)

Comment: @RadenJohannesHeryoPriambodo this means your spider already crawled the page. So there might be a flaw with your next page logic somewhere. You can force crawl by adding `dont_filter=True` argument to your `Request` objects but that's a very lazy solution.

Comment: the page looping on page 32. What's happen?,  update the code on first thread.

Comment: that's exactly what `dont_filter` does. Your next page logic doesn't find correct next page on those pages so you end up in a loop.